# How to find last occurrence of some character in the whole vector<string> then split the string to three separate elements

Tags: c++, c++11

If I have vector of string `vector<string> vec` and want to find last occurrence of some character `','` in the **complete vector** then split the string to three separate elements in the vector in the same place.

```
vector<string> vec1 = { "string1","str,in,g2" , ",string3 " , "my,target" ," string4" };
vector<string> vec2 = { "string1","str,in,g2" , ",string3 " , "my,tar,get" ," string4" };
```

I want to convert the vector to:

```
vector<string> vec1 = { "string1","str,in,g2" , ",string3 " , "my" , "," , "target" , "string4" };
vector<string> vec1 = { "string1","str,in,g2" , ",string3 " , "my,tar" , "," , "get" , "string4" };
```

is there a short way to that rather than check every string from the end of the vector and copy it to new one ?

I'am using c++11 .

Comment: In the example, why `str,in,g2` isn't split too?

Comment: Why is `"my,target"` and `"my,tar,get"` separated, but not `"str,in,g2"` ?? Could you provide more or cleaner examples?

Comment: @Acorn and RoQuOTriX: To emphasise the title of the question: "How to find _last occurrence_ of some character _in vector<string>_ then split the string to three separate elements" It's about the last `,` in the whole vector.

Comment: Just to clarify, not the last occurrence in each string, but the last occurrence in the complete vector? The begin by iterating *backwards* over the vector, then [find the last](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of) comma and if found split the string, insert after the current position, and stop searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use reverse iterators:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> vec = { "string1","str,in,g2" , ",string3 " , "my,target" ," string4" };
    for (auto it = vec.rbegin(); it != vec.rend(); it++) {
        std::string str = *it;
        auto comma_pos = std::find(str.rbegin(), str.rend(), ',');
        if (comma_pos != str.rend()) {
            std::string str1(str.begin(), comma_pos.base() - 1);
            std::string str2(",");
            std::string str3(comma_pos.base(), str.end());
            auto insert_it = it.base();
            insert_it = vec.insert(insert_it, str3);
            insert_it = vec.insert(insert_it, str2);
            insert_it = vec.insert(insert_it, str1);
            vec.erase(insert_it - 1);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use find to get the last entry that has ',' like this

```
vector<string> v = ....;
iter = find(v.rbegin(), v.rend(),
            [](const string& s) {return s.find(',') != string::npos;});
```

After checking you've actually found something split the entry.

```
// Find the last one, no need to check for not found, we know the string contains 
// a comma. You check above.
auto pos = iter->rfind(','); 
auto first = iter->substr(0, pos);
auto last = iter->substr(pos + 1);

*iter = first;
iter = v.insert(iter + 1, ",");  // No need to extract the comma since it's always a comma.
v.insert(iter + 1, last);
```

As you can see there's a bit of iterator logic here. Make sure you run with a debugger over a few cases to make sure we got it right.

Comment: Shouldn't the `*(iter++) = first;` be just `*iter = first`? We want to overide the element that contained the `,`, not the one after it.

Comment: @churill in this case ++ aplies after the change. It will override the element with the ','. I need the next one for the insert, because insert puts the element before the given iterator. I haven't had enough coffee today, so please try it in a debugger first, in case I still got something wrong.

Comment: Alternatively you meant to use `*iter++` (without braces), which does assign `iter` before incrementing it. Should work now.